# Is it possible to use bootstrap on your existing code?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have already built a site using CSS. Now looking back I regret not taking the chance of using Bootstrap. My website is already built and styled. My questions is, is it possible to use bootstrap even though you already have styled you website without having to remove all the CSS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bootstrap uses a set of pre-configured classes to implement it's styling rules..

So unless you somehow incorporated the same class names in your site and intended the same styling as was intended by the Bootstrap developers, you are going to have to make the necessary changes on your own.

That said, if your project is intended to be extended in the future, it may still be a good idea do re-work what you did up until now with Bootstrap, in order to save time in the future (I am assuming that the project is not very large in scope).

Comment: Thanks for your comment, do you think it's worth it for me to start over using bootstrap?

Answer (score 0):

There are few things you need to know:

- Bootstrap uses `box-sizing: content-box` so if you are not, it will probably impact all your padding/border stuff.
- Bootstrap comes with a reset and few helpers with generic names that can interfere with your own style.

That said it's totally ok to add bootstrap to your project and it should be smooth.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, do you think it's worth it for me to start over using bootstrap?